# how to sleep just one function of the code in python?

Tags: python, function, time, sleep

i am writing a code in python and i just want one function to sleep not the whole code in `time.sleep()`. but i couldn't find a way.
my code:

```
from time import sleep
a = int()
def calc(a,b):
    while True:
         a=a*b
         if a >> 12:
              sleep(12)
              #i just want this func to sleep here.
def print(msg):
    while True:
          msg = a
          print(msg)
          #i don't want this func to sleep
```

what should i do?

Comment: The second function is not going to sleep

Comment: When calling a function, the caller stops until the called function returns. `sleep()` is no exception there. Unless you're using any kind of concurrency (threads, async, timers) you can't have other code run while sleeping somewhere else.

Comment: Well, for one thing, it's unclear how and when you plan to call these functions. (You've only shown *defining* them.) Second, what does your intended output actually look like? What should it print, and when / in what order? I'm not sure what your actual goal is.

Answer (score 1):

Use asyncio

```
import asyncio

async def calc(a,b):
while True:
     a=a*b
     if a >> 12:
          await asyncio.sleep(12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to read a little about the function `time.sleep`. Here's what the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) says about it:

> Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

The function pauses the program at the desired place, if you call it. It does not stop the other function.

Answer (score 0):

code inside f1() function will be executed 2 seconds after running the code, but in that time f2() function will be executed.

```
from time import time, sleep
def f1():
    print("Function1")
def f2():
    print("Function2")

t1 = time() # Stores current system time in seconds
print(t1)

time_to_delay_f1 = 2
while True:
    if time()-t1 > time_to_delay_f1:  # time()-t1 is the time passed after assigning t1 = time(), [see before 2 lines]
        f1()
    else:
        f2()
```